# Image Animation Failed to play

Tags: android

I have used below code to play image animation. But after clicking button, animation couldn't play. Note : I have put rotator.xml in res/anim folder.

**AnimationActivity.java**

```
package com.example.animationdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                final Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotator);
                myImage.startAnimation(myRotation);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**rotator.xml :**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”">
android:duration="”4000”"
android:fromdegrees="”0”"
android:pivotx="”50%”"
android:pivoty="”50%”"
android:todegrees="”360”"
android:toyscale="”0.0”"
</rotate>
```

**activity_animation.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AnimationActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="109dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.animationdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animationdemo.AnimationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: In rotator.xml : why you r providing with totoally"""" provide like i provided android:fromdegrees="0"..

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

Format of comma which created mess in your file because you might have copied from some webpage

**Solution:**

replace your **rotator.xml** with following code:

```
    <rotate xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”">
android:duration="4000"
android:fromdegrees="0"
android:pivotx="50%"
android:pivoty="50%"
android:todegrees="360"
android:toyscale="0.0"
</rotate>
```

**EDIT :**

Change

`AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotator)`

to

```
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationActivity.this, R.anim.rotator)
```

Comment: I have done changes as per above suggestions, but still it not worked. Is there any special type of image file needed to work this animation? I have used default ic_launcher.png image in drawable folder for checking purpose.

Comment: @Ketan: may be you are facing problems due to context,I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<rotate xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”">
android:duration="4000"
android:fromdegrees="0"
android:pivotx="50”"
android:pivoty="50%"
android:todegrees="360"
android:toyscale="0.0"
</rotate>
```

Try to place this file  rotator,xml

Comment: I have done changes as per above suggestions, but still it not worked. Is there any special type of image file needed to work this animation? I have used default ic_launcher.png image in drawable folder for checking purpose.

Comment: No any error. Just after clicking button, image flip animation can't work.